# How do I tidy up my vimrc file?

Tags: vim, autocmd

My Vim configuration file is getting bigger *(15KB+)*. And I try not to make my vim launch slower by sourcing more *(larger)* files at startup. For the same purpose I use only essential plugins and I try to keep the number of plugin as less as possible.

So, somewhere in my .vimrc file, I have these lines:

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
autocmd FileType python setlocal textwidth=78
autocmd FileType python match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
autocmd FileType python inoremap <F5> <esc>:upd\|!python %<cr>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <F5> :upd\|!python %<cr>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <leader>8 :w\|call Flake8()<cr>
autocmd FileType python setlocal formatoptions-=t
autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Flake8()
```

Now I see in first 7 lines, all lines have `autocmd FileType python` in common. So my thinking is, if we manage to replace all those word with something less then Vim will fire up faster. But I don't know how to do that.

Can we group them? How? Anything else?

Comment: Mandatory troll: `:%d` cleans your vimrc up the best. Alternatively, `:new|saveas! $MYVIMRC` is quite effective

Comment: Also, slightly less trolling, [`:help autocmd-groups`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-groups)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put

```
setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 textwidth=78 formatoptions-=t
match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
inoremap <F5> <esc>:upd\|!python %<cr>
nnoremap <F5> :upd\|!python %<cr>
nnoremap <leader>8 :w\|call Flake8()<cr>
```

in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Vim will read this file only when you open a Python file.

I've been meaning to do this for some time, actually. And for the same reasons.

Comment: This shadows the default `ftplugin/python.vim`, and it only works (i.e. doesn't prevent the default settings) because it doesn't `:let b:did_ftplugin = 1`. I find it clearer to put this into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`; that's what the after directories are for.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, you are right. I've updated my answer with `/after`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Filetype-specific stuff should be moved to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, as romainl has already pointed out.

I moved all my custom mappings and commands into `~/.vim/plugin/my{mappings,commands}.vim`, and mostly only put real settings (the `:set` commands) and plugin customizations into `.vimrc`. Any mappings / commands that aren't simple one-liners and delegate to functions then use the autoload mechanism. This keeps the amount of stuff read at startup small.

*TL,DR: Autoload is great; all plugins should use it.*

Answer (score 2):

I am using a scheme where a group of options is set in a function that is called by an auto command.

```
function! s:C_options()
    setlocal cinoptions={0,:1s,g1s,t0,(0,=.5s
    setlocal noautoindent
    setlocal nosmartindent
    setlocal cindent
    call s:PROG_options()
endfunction

autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.c call s:C_options()
```

It is quite similar to using a filetype but you can use nested call, like having general programming options in `s:PROG_options()`, so you should be able to reduce further the size of your `.vimrc`.

The `after\filetype`solution might be more efficient regarding initial load time, but I would rather have most of my customization in a single `.vimrc` than scattered in the `.vim`directory.

Answer (score 1):

At least you can merge the first two lines with the 7th

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 textwidth=78 formatoptions-=t
autocmd FileType python match ErrorMsg '\%>80v.\+'
autocmd FileType python inoremap <F5> <esc>:upd\|!python %<cr>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <F5> :upd\|!python %<cr>
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <leader>8 :w\|call Flake8()<cr>
autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Flake8()
```

But I can't imagine how you can get rid of the others. On the other hand I don't think that these autocmd commands are taking so long to execute.